# Best resources for converting C/C++ dll headers to Delphi?

Tags: c++, c, delphi, dll, header

A rather comprehensive site explaining the difficulties and solutions involved in using a dll written in c/c++ and the conversion of the .h header file to delphi/pascal was posted to a mailing list I was on recently, so I thought I'd share it, and invite others to post other useful resources for this, whether they be links, conversion tools, or book/paper titles.

One resource per answer please, so we'll end up with the most popular/best resources bubbling to the top.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Over at [Rudy's Delphi Corner](http://rvelthuis.de/index.html), he has an [excellent article about the pitfalls of converting C/C++ to Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html). In my opinion, this is essential information when attempting this task. Here is the description:

> This article is meant for everyone who
>   needs to translate C/C++ headers to
>   Delphi. I want to share some of the
>   pitfalls you can encounter when
>   converting from C or C++. This article
>   is not a tutorial, just a discussion
>   of frequently encountered problem
>   cases. It is meant for the beginner as
>   well as for the more experienced
>   translator of C and C++.

He also wrote a "[Conversion Helper Package](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/convertpack.html)" that installs into the Delphi IDE which aids in converting C/C++ code to Delphi:

[image]
<sub>(source: [rvelthuis.de](http://rvelthuis.de/images/convertpackshaded.png))</sub>

His other relevant articles on this topic include:

- [Using C++ Objects in Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html)
- [Using C object files in Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cobjs.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, this website is not up, at the moment. Try http://praxis-velthuis.de/rdc/articles/articles-convert.html for now. I hope the original site will be up again, soon.

Comment: Archive.org has it backed up too: http://web.archive.org/web/20150222134925/http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html

Answer (score 6):

[Article](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html#main) at Rudy's Delphi Corner

Comment: Looks like this was by far the most popular resource, but I've accepted Mick's answer rather than my own, as it provided more detail

Answer (score 2):

Also, CodeGear hosts a rudimentary translation tool called [CToPas](http://cc.codegear.com/item/23991) (written by Ural Gunaydin).

Answer (score 2):

I would like to highlight the [Jedi Api Library](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/home/), it is the Delphi translation of the Windows SDK headers. Might save you a lot of work if you need to translate headers from the SDK and is of course a good sample of conversions!

Answer (score 2):

Since FreePascal is aimed at Delphi compatibiltiy among other things, i think H2Pas may be helpful too.

https://www.freepascal.org/tools/h2pas.var

Answer (score 1):

[HeadConv](http://www.drbob42.com/headconv/) from DrBob is used quite a lot too, although I concur with Graza that manual translation is best.

Answer (score 1):

use this option so the byte alignment is the same as C/C++ and then you don't need to add padding bytes in structs.

{$MINENUMSIZE 4}