# Convert C Header to delphi

Tags: c, delphi, dll, header

```
int  WINAPI  BiMICRSetReadBackFunction(
    int  nHandle,
    int  (CALLBACK  *pMicrCB)(void),
    LPBYTE  pReadBuffSize,
    LPBYTE  readCharBuff,
    LPBYTE  pStatus,
    LPBYTE  pDetail);

    typedef int (CALLBACK* MICRCallback)(void);
    typedef int (CALLBACK* StatusCallback)(DWORD);

    int WINAPI BiSetInkStatusBackFunction(int nHandle,
        int (CALLBACK *pStatusCB)(DWORD dwStatus)
);
```

I need to convert this function to Delphi.

I tried to use `headconv4.2` but the resulting static unit is not completed, and errors occur when compiling.

Thanks in advance for  your kind help :D

Comment: +1 for your question, as I totally disagree with the two "close" votes (not a real question; too localised) for a question that is easy to answer, that points out `HeadConv` often isn't a good solution, and allows the answerer to explain some generic information on [C to Delphi header conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100596/best-resources-for-converting-c-c-dll-headers-to-delphi). It clearly shows that [moderators should be less than a machine](http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/s/96502)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing `WINAPI` and `CALLBACK` always being `__stdcall`, `DWORD` being `unsigned int` and `LPBYTE` as `unsigned char *`, you could try this *dirty conversion* I made:

```delphi
unit UHeader;

interface

// Data types

type
  PByte = ^Byte;
  PPByte = ^PByte;

// Prototypes

type
  TMICRCallback = function: Integer; stdcall;
  TStatusCallback = function(dwParam: Cardinal): Integer; stdcall;

// Functions

type
  TBiMICRSetReadBackFunction =
    function(nHande: Integer;
             pMicrCB: TMICRCallback;
             pReadBuffSize: PByte;
             readCharBuff: PByte;
             pStatus: PByte;
             pDetail: PByte
    ): Integer; stdcall;

var
  BiMICRSetReadBackFunction: TBiMICRSetReadBackFunction;

type
  TBiSetInkStatusBackFunction =
    function(nHandle: Integer;
             pStatusCB: TStatusCallback
    ): Integer; stdcall;

var
  BiSetInkStatusBackFunction: TBiSetInkStatusBackFunction;

implementation

end.
```

I'm not entirely sure, though, if this is correct... but this could be a path for you to try to convert it yourself.

Comment: +1. Just FYI: `PByte` and `PPByte` are already defined in Delphi, as is `DWORD`. Most of the common Windows API data types (like `HDC`, `HWND`, etc.) are defined in the `System` or `Windows` unit, and have been since Delphi 1 was released.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for the info, I've never noticed that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's true, but for the purpose of `LPBYTE`, I think deriving `Byte` is a better option...

Comment: OK, so why are you talking about char then?

Comment: Because `LPBYTE` is declared as follows: `typedef BYTE far *LPBYTE;` where `typedef unsigned char BYTE;` according to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx)

Comment: OK, fair enough. I'll buy that.

Comment: note that in  C headers, a pointer to a parameter often means the Pascal equivalent of `var` or `out` and sometimes even `const`. That reduces the risk of passing a pointer to something you do not want to be written to. The Windows API imports in Delphi show a lot of examples of that.

Comment: Yep, this is totally true. But for simplicity I didn't use `var`, etc. because the asker didn't provided too much info on that. But it should be simple to do that though. That's why I describe my conversion as *dirty*, ha.

Comment: @David bacause that is C. There is no distinct shortint/byte/ansichar types in C, but a pair "signed/unsigned char", and both of those are both integral and character types. That is basics of C AFAIR. Char* may be string - or may be just byte buffer, dependign on context.

Answer (score 3):

A literal translation would be:

```
type
  MICRCallback = function: Integer; stdcall; 
  StatusCallback = function(dwStatus: DWORD): Integer; stdcall; 

function BiMICRSetReadBackFunction( 
  nHandle: Integer; 
  pMicrCB: MICRCallback; 
  pReadBuffSize: PByte; 
  readCharBuff: PByte; 
  pStatus: PByte; 
  pDetail: PByte
): Integer; stdcall; 

function BiSetInkStatusBackFunction(
  nHandle: Integer;
  pStatusCB: StatusCallback
): Integer; stdcall;
```

If you are importing functions from a DLL, then you need to add the DLL filename to the function declarations:

```
function BiMICRSetReadBackFunction( 
  nHandle: Integer; 
  pMicrCB: MICRCallback; 
  pReadBuffSize: PByte; 
  readCharBuff: PByte; 
  pStatus: PByte; 
  pDetail: PByte
): Integer; stdcall; external 'filename.dll';

function BiSetInkStatusBackFunction(
  nHandle: Integer;
  pStatusCB: StatusCallback
): Integer; stdcall; external 'filename.dll';
```

Comment: Thanks :D Im Going to try this examples.