# How to convert C++ header file to delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, header-files

I'm converting C++ header to delphi pas file. First, I converted C++ header using HeadConv 4.0 from Dr.Bob module. But it failed compiling.
Can anyone help for this converting?

****** C++ header ******

```
#if !defined(____KKK_Module__)

#define ____KKK_Module__

#ifdef KKK_MODULE_EXPORTS

#define KKK_MODULE_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

#else

#define KKK_MODULE_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)

#endif

KKK_MODULE_API int _stdcall KKK_Creat();

......
```

Above code was converted Delphi code which leads error as below;

****** Delphi code ******

```
{$IFDEF KKK_MODULE_EXPORTS}

const 
 KKK_MODULE_API = extern 'C' __declspec(dllexport);  **//error**

{$ELSE}

const
  KKK_MODULE_API = extern 'C' __declspec(dllimport);  **//error**

{$ENDIF}

var
  KKK_Creat: function: KKK_MODULE_API INT cdecl  {$IFDEF WIN32} stdcall 
{$ENDIF};

.........
```

Cause of error is that 'extern' is not the reserved syntex of Delphi.
I don't know how to replace it with Delphi code and need any help.

Comment: There's no such thing as a C# header file. You mean C++ header file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100596/best-resources-for-converting-c-c-dll-headers-to-delphi

Comment: `function KKK_Creat: Integer; stdcall; external 'TheLibrary.dll' name 'KKK_Creat';`

Comment: HeadConv is completely broken. Use `h2p`.

Comment: My advice, and I have done quite a few header conversions: don't use an automated conversion tool. Most of them will produce wrong or useless code for some of the header. I prefer to convert manually, with the help of [my Conversion Pack](http://praxis-velthuis.de/rdc/programs/convertpack.html) and some of the macr recording facilities of the IDE. This works well and quickly produces rock-solid translations Try to read my article about this ([Pitfalls of converting](http://praxis-velthuis.de/rdc/articles/articles-convert.html)) too.

Answer (score 2):

That is not C#, it is C++.

The conditional section is a very common pattern to allow the header file to be used both when building the library and when importing it. You are only importing so don't need to translate that part.

You are then left with just a single function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int _stdcall KKK_Creat();
```

The use of `extern "C"` suppresses C++ name mangling. You don't translate that.

Loosely, you translate `__declspec(dllimport)` with the `external` directive.

Translate it all to:

```
function KKK_Creat: Integer; stdcall; external libname;
```

where `libname` is a string containing the name of the DLL.

You need to check what name was used to export the function. If the library was built without a .def file the function names will be decorated. That function would be named `KKK_Creat@0`. Use a tool like dumpbin or Dependency Viewer to check the exported function names in the DLL.

FWIW, I've never found an effective general purpose header translator and have always found it best to do this manually, or to write a bespoke header specific translator.

Comment: FWIW, if the library was built with a .def file, the names will not be decorated.

Comment: @Rudy Thanks, that's what I meant to say, but fluffed it